# Set no build in IntelliJ Run\Debug configuration

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there any way to set Run\Debug configuration in IntelliJ, in `Before Launch` panel to set nothing instead of default `Build`?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Directly above `Build` you'll see `+` and `-` buttons.

If you select `Build` and then click the `-` button then that the build action will be removed and nothing will be run before launching the test.

Note: the purpose of building by default before running a test is to ensure that your test runs with the latest code. If you remove this action then your test might not run with the latest code.

For more details see the section titled "Before launch" in [the docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configurations-dialog.html) ...

[image]

Comment: it's ok, but I want a solution to set no build by default in any new Run\Debug configuration.